# Need a help in understanding the proof of a Lemma 5.1 is Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The Lemma said: "If $f$ is a linear functional on $H$ and $f(x_{0}) \neq 0$ for some $ x_{0} \in H $, then every $x \in H$ has the form $$x = \beta x_{0} + z, \beta \in \mathbb{C}, z \in Ker f.$$ "

And its proof as written in the book is:

" **Proof:**

Take $\beta = \frac{f(x)}{f(x_{0})}$ and $z = x - \beta x_{0}.$ "

But I can not understand the importance of the $\beta$ given in the proof, Also it is not clear for me the total idea of the proof, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: I guess you have written some wrong expression?

Comment: No I did not have any wrong expression  as I could see ..... I have revised .... do you have the book?

Comment: Anyway, someone else has provided an answer, you may look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see, with your own notation:

$$f(z)=f(x-\beta x_0)=f(x)-\beta f(x_0)=f(x)-\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}f(x_0)=0\implies z\in \ker f$$

and also

$$\beta x_0+z=\beta x_0+(x-\beta x_0)=x$$

So you can see *why* they defined $\;\beta\;$ as they did: if fulfills what the lemma promises!

Answer (score 0):

In some sense $x$ can be decomposed as the sum of an element of the kernel of $f$ and an element of the space which "is" the range of $f$. Note that the range of $f$ can be taken as $\left<f(x_{0})\right>$, and if we want to find a subspace of the domain of $f$ which "is" $\left<f(x_{0})\right>$, the map $\varphi:\left<x_{0}\right>\rightarrow\left<f(x_{0})\right>$ defined by $\varphi(\gamma x_{0})=\gamma f(x_{0})$ will do. As a result, with $\beta=\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x_{0})}$, $\varphi(\beta x_{0})=\beta\varphi(x_{0})=\beta f(x_{0})=f(x)$, so the part of $x$ decomposed to $\left<x_{0}\right>$ should correspond to $\beta x_{0}$, then the rest of the work is to check whether $x-\beta x_{0}$ falls into the kernel of $f$, as @Don Antonio has checked it, so the constant $\beta$ fits perfectly with the expected decomposition.

Comment: What do you mean by this sign <>?

Comment: The subspace generated by $a$, essentially, $\left<a\right>=\{ka: k\in{\bf{C}}\}$.